# Preserve whitespace in html

Tags: html, xaml

In xaml I can make whitespace relevant (that is not ignored) by using the xml:space attribute on a tag. Reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788720.aspx

Is there any way to make whitespace relevant in html?

Update:

Finally went with:

```
<p style="white-space: pre">
Hi   This
    is
 an    example
</p>
```

Although Aziz shaikh solution also works fine as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can specify the [white space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_white-space) property in css

Answer (score 7):

Don't know whether I understand your question correctly, but if you want to preserve the White Spaces in html , **pre** is the tag you are looking for

```
  <html>
    ....

    <pre>
      hi   this
         is
      an    example
    </pre>
    </html>
```

it will provide you:

```
 Hi   This
    is
 an    example
```

Comment: Yes pre is what I am looking for except that pre renders in a console font on browsers. I want it to use the default font yet preserve space exactly like pre

Comment: just add the style attribute to the tag and you should be able to do whatever styling you want. <pre style= "font=Times new Roman"> like this

Answer (score 3):

It is not about "relevance" but how the browser has been told to render the text. The `pre` tag renders whitespaces without collapsing them.

This rendering property can be controlled on any element by the [CSS white-space property](http://file:///Users/hoylen/Documents/Home/specifications/w3c/css/css_1.0/index.html#white-space).

```
p.foobar { white-space: pre }

<p class="foobar">abc   def</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is using a non-breaking space, as in `&nbsp;`, for horizontal whitespace, and `<br>` for a line break.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<pre>` with css styling. Check this [fiddle as demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hXH38/).

```
<pre style="font:inherit">
    This       is       a
              pre
    test
</pre>
```